Reopen my question after adding debugging details
I'm not sure about my next steps and what to do, so decided to ask here. If I made a mistake, asking a question here, please point me in the right direction.
Here is my question: ModuleNotFoundError with pre-commit mypy. Currently, it got closed with the flag “This question needs debugging details. It is not currently accepting answer”. I tried to add as much debugging details in the question as possible: current configuration, how to launch, error output, attempt to fix, possible problems (moreover, I believe I found the solution, but can't post it, because the question is closed).
But it seems like nothing is moving further. And I don't know the status and what to expect.
And I'm quite surprised about the comments to my initial question. ”read the mirrors-mypy README, it has the answer”.
Does this comment suits the site rules? As I remember, you can't just answer “read the docs”, you must be specific.

Now you wait until your question had time to be reviewed. And either is reopened or left closed because there is something else wrong with it. See What if I disagree with the closure of a question? How can I reopen it? It's been only 2 days, we're all volunteers.

“Does this comment suits the site rules? As I remember, you can't just answer “read the docs”, you must be specific.” - You received a comment not an answer, if you find the comment unhelpful flag it, and it will be deleted. If it was an answer you could downvote it or flag it for not being an answer.

Aside from my answer here, I would advise you to read Advice for non-native English speakers.

First off, this part could be written more clearly:

I'm trying to use mypy with precommit hooks.

I think it means: "I'm trying to use the mypy-mirror plugin for precommit to set up a pre-commit hook that will run MyPy when I check in the code". But I'd prefer not to have to guess.

And when I try to use precommit git commit -a -m "commit message", I got such error:

This is not a complete error message. You should copy and paste starting from the line that says Traceback (most recent call last): all the way to the end.
But also, we don't have enough context to understand which config/settings/ folder this is. Is it part of your own project? Part of the precommit implementation? Part of the mypy-mirror implementation? Something else?
A proper Minimal Reproducible Example for your problem would show a complete set of project files that reproduces the problem - not just the config files you showed, but also example Python source code - even if it's just one file with print("test") or whatever. And we should see the directory structure for these files, too.
It's especially important to understand whether specific import statements are needed in your own code to trigger the problem, or just what.

The error is that there is an import in setting.py file.

No, it clearly doesn't say that. The part of the stack trace that you show, mentions a settings folder with two differently named .py files in it.

I've tried to add environ to additional_dependencies, but no success, get another error: ... (looks like outdated syntax for Python 3.12).

Well, yes. If you look up that package name on PyPI you'll see that it only ever had one release, in 2007. If you're trying to work at this level of automation and environment management, then you should understand by now that package names don't match import names (this is asked about all the time, but I don't have a proper duplicate handy for it).

And looks like the problem is not connected with adding missed dependencies, because I get the same error for each dependency in the project.

You mean the ModuleNotFoundError, right? That isn't clear. But also, I can't understand your reasoning. That sounds like a reason exactly why it is connected. (Especially given the documentation that was already linked to you.)

Ok, will take in mind, thx for your time
